# Is ammunition included with "choose simple/martial weapon"?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment

If something says "any martial/simple weapon" in character creation I think it includes ranged weapons too, but does it include ammunition? Does my bow come with arrows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically when it lists a bow or simple crossbow specifically in the equipment list, it is accompanied with the text "and 20 bolts" or "and 20 arrows."

I'd argue that choosing an ammunition weapon would come with same amount of ammunition, as RAI.

I could see a DM arguing the opposite, "Since it doesn't say you get ammo, you need to buy it." Because it is Rules As Written.

Since 20 bolts or 20 arrows cost 1 gp, and 20 sling bullets cost 4 cp, I don't see a reason why this should be a sticking point either way. It's not game breaking to start with it, and it isn't bank breaking to buy it.  The only problem I see is if the DM lets you have the weapon, and you assume you have the ammo until you go to use it.

Comment: well, if you choose the equipment from the list, you don't get the starting gold, so you can't buy ammo, or am I forgetting something?

Comment: @Patta The background that you choose does give you a small amount of starting gold (usually 5-15, depending on the one chosen).

Comment: Some do, yes, but as far as I know you can not spend them at character Creation?

Comment: @Patta: Nothing prevents you from shopping at/before the start except your DM and maybe the starting setting.

Comment: Technically the rules only allow you to spend your starting Gold if you choose Not to take the starting equipment from your Class, by strict RAW, which is what I was referring to. I might be missing some rule somewhere, but that would not be something for the Comments :D

Answer (score 2):

Ask your DM.

If a class or background starting package gives you any simple or martial weapon then that means a weapon on the weapon table.

By strict reading, arrows are not simple or martial weapons and you would have to buy them out of the cash you get. By a broader reading that the intent is to give you a weapon you can actually use, they would be included.